# Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Todo: (?)

Tags: angular6, rxjs6

This is what my Todo class looks like. I guess it has something to do with an update and what I declared in the constructor. Thankful for any clue.

```
  export class Todo {
  id: number;
  title = '';
  complete = false;

  constructor(values: Object = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, values);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into the issue and looks like your code is correct. How you are importing class that might be the issue.. find the solution below how I approached

Todo Class:

```
export class Todo {
  id: number;
  title = '';
  complete = false;
  constructor (values:Object = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, values);
  }
}
```

component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
**import {Todo} from './Todo';**

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Lazy loading feature modules';
  myTodo = new Todo({manas:'name'});
  constructor() {
  console.log(this.myTodo);
  }
}
```

console: 
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmjmQ.png)

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. Solved it!